# Change image relative width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

How to change dynamically the relative percent width of an image?

```html
<div style="width: 350px; background-color: #DDDDDD">
    <img id="gradient" src="img.png" style="width: 74.074%;"></img>
</div>
```

I've failed to get the width with jquery using `attr()` or dot:

```js
<input type="submit" value="button" />

<script>                                                                      
$(function() {
  $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
    .button()
    .click(function( event ) {
     $("#gradiant").width;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery will get the width always in `PX` (instead %) but a bit of math should help you: `imgW*100/parentW = %`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("#gradiant").width();
```

`width()`:

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the width of every matched element.
>   Or:

```
$("#gradiant").outerWidth();
```

`Outerwidth()`:

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding and border.

You can also pass a Boolean to the method `.outerWidth(true)`, to include the `margin` of the (first) element in the returned width.

Incidentally, I can't find *any* reference to a `button()` method in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), and a search returns only the `:button` *selector*, using a non-existent method *will* [result in an error](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EZCjb/) (check the console).

References:

- [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/).
- [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: nether `alert($("#gradiant").width());` nor `alert($("#gradiant").outerWidth());`

Comment: Did you notice the part where I mentioned there being no `button()` method? Because if you look in the console, you'll see an error: [`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'button'`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EZCjb/). Once that method is removed, and the typo (`gradient`/`gradiant`) is fixed, it works with [`width()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EZCjb/1/), [`outerWidth()`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EZCjb/2/) *and* [`outerWidth(true)`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/EZCjb/3/).

Comment: Isn't .button part of jQuery UI? Perhaps that's causing some issues with the width commands. @Philippe: try to break it down, do a console.log on the $("gradiant") and work your way from there.

Answer (score 0):

`gradiAnt` != `gradient`
`<img></img>` != `<img />`

```
<div style="width: 350px; background-color: #DDDDDD">
    <img id="gradient" src="img.png" style="width: 74.074%;" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="button" />

<script>                                                                      
$(function() {
  $( "input[type=submit]").click(function() {
     var imgW = $("#gradient").width(); // in PX (Number)
     var parentW= $("#gradient").closest('div').width();
     var percent= imgW*100/parentW;

     alert(imgW +' '+ parentW +' '+ percent +'%');

  });
});
</script>
```